# Trying to kill a temp mdb that was imported into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to kill a *.mdb file in VBA, however I'm getting a Permission denied as it is being used in Excel.

```
If (fso.FileExists(tablepath & tablename & ".mdb")) Then
    Kill tablepath & tablename & ".mdb"
End If
```

I wanted to import it and then delete it. I thought that the following import closed off the connection to the mdb once it had import, obviously not.

How can I close the connection?

This is MS Excel 2010 32bit.

```
    With Workbooks(new_workbook_name).Sheets(FolderName & " Detail").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & tablepath & tablename & ".mdb;" _
        , _
        "Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:D" _
        , _
        "atabase Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Glob" _
        , _
        "al Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=Fals" _
        , _
        "e;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Supp" _
        , "ort Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False"), _
        Destination:=Range("A1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array(tablename)
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .SourceDataFile = _
        tablepath & tablename & ".mdb"
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_" & tablename
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the string QueryTable add the line:

```
.MaintainConnection = False
```

In that case after the query the connection are released. The default value is True.